# How can I assign and keep more than one value to the same variable in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, properties, iteration, owlready

I wonder how can I assign more than one value to a variable, without loosing the first value assigned.
I have the following example, where a certain sales product (in one column) is assigned a package name value (in another column) :

Sales product = Package name

ABC  = Package1

ABC = Package2

As you can see sales product "ABC" has two different values for package name, "Package1" and "Package2".

I am assigning object properties to an ontology by using OWLready2, and to do this dynamically, I am using a for loop like this:

```
            for i in input_list[1:]:
                onto[i[0]].has_package = onto[i[1]]
```

With this I can have:  ABC.has_package = Package1

The problem is when I go to the next line, there is a new package name value for the same product ABC. Therefore at the end my ontology only considers this last value: ABC.has_package = Package2

My question is, if there is a way in the "for loop" to keep all the possible values for my product "ABC". At the end I would like to both Package1 and Package2 to be assigned and saved.

Comment: Please could add to your example code to make it runnable, i.e. initialise all variables.

Answer (score 0):

Assignments usually overwrite the old value. Form what I understand you probably want to use `onto[i[0]].has_package.append(onto[i[1]])`.